# Configure Always Encrypted for SQL Azure with KeyVault using C#/.NET

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I have a working script via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-keys-using-powershell (KeyVault + SQL Azure setup). Now I have plain Azure PS (KeyVault creation), reflected assemblies (SMO, SqlClient, ConnectionInfo) and the SqlAzure module (column encryption).

Long story short - could I do all that in C#? (I have an existing workflow using the fluent management libraries, and shelling out to PS is something I'd like to avoid if possible).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do that. One idea that comes to mind is to generate separate AAD applications (Id, Secret pairs, See "Generate Application ID and Secret" section of [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/11/10/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always-encrypted/) article) for each role with appropriate permissions and take the take ID, secret as an input from the user. Also, [the article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/11/10/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always-encrypted/) describes how to integrate Azure Key vault with C# application and use it for Always Encrypted. If you have additional questions, please share them in the comment section so I can help you answer them.

Comment: That is not really close to where I want to go - I want to configure KV (easy), MSI and then consequently always encrypted in C# - with whatever management library is available. (haven't yet looked at SMO)

Comment: You have the right idea, SMO will be useful for managing SQL Server objects. Is there is any specific concern/problem that you foresee?

Comment: Question would be what the equivalents from SqlAzure module would be for Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext, New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey, New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings, Set-SqlColumnEncryption et al.